# how to drop foreign key constraint for a foreign key with no name on alembic?

Tags: mysql, database, alembic

I have a table which i created as shown below

```
op.create_table('test',
                    sa.Column('userid', sa.String(length=60), nullable=False),
                    sa.Column('page_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
                    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['userid'], ['map.userid']),
                )
```

I want add a ondelete="CASCADE" constraint on the foreign key. 
I understand we need to do drop_contraint and create_foreign_key. But how do i drop_contraint foreign key which has no Name in alembic?

Comment: Please google your title.

Answer (score 3):

If ForeignKey was created without name, then the name will be autogenerated. The format of this name is dependent on the database you’re using.

The name can be found, for instance, like this:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM information_schema.key_column_usage 
    WHERE table_name='$table_name';
```