# How to make alembic or flask migrate name foreign keys when autogenerating migrations?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I've been struggling with this issue on and off for quite some time, and strangely could not find a straightforward question/answer combo on this on SO. Related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381574/how-to-drop-foreign-key-constraint-for-a-foreign-key-with-no-name-on-alembic) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63732400/flask-migrate-creating-foreign-key-with-none-for-no-apparent-reason). I finally found a solution so I will ask and answer my own question.

In Flask SQLAlchemy (and regular SQLAlchemy), you can have a column like this:

```py
class Character(db.model):
  background_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('backgrounds.id'))
```

When you run `flask db migrate`, or `alembic revision --autogenerate`, this will result in an operation that looks like this:

```py
def upgrade():
  op.create_foreign_key(None, 'characters', 'backgrounds', ['background_id'], ['id'])

def downgrade():
  op.drop_constraint(None, 'characters', type_='foreignkey')
```

The `None` here is bad. In fact, if you try to downgrade later, this will always fail, because `drop_constraint` needs the name of the constraint.

You can change this every time you generate a migration, like this:

```py
def upgrade():
  op.create_foreign_key('fk_characters_backgrounds', 'characters', 'backgrounds', ['background_id'], ['id'])

def downgrade():
  op.drop_constraint('fk_characters_backgrounds', 'characters', type_='foreignkey')
```

Which works!

But if you're like me, you don't want to have to remember to do this every time you autogenerate a revision with a foreign key.

So the question is, how can we make this automatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an answer to this question in the best practices suggested [here](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/naming.html#the-importance-of-naming-constraints), at the end of the section on The Importance of Naming Conventions. The solution is to add a `naming_convention` to your `sqlalchemy` metadata, like this:

```py
convention = {
  "ix": "ix_%(column_0_label)s",
  "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
  "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(constraint_name)s",
  "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
  "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s"
}

metadata = MetaData(naming_convention=convention)
```

More specifically, with `Flask-SQLAlchemy`, do this when initializing your db:

```py
from sqlalchemy import MetaData

convention = {
  "ix": "ix_%(column_0_label)s",
  "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
  "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(constraint_name)s",
  "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
  "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s"
}

db = SQLAlchemy(metadata=MetaData(naming_convention=convention))
```

And voila! If you run `autogenerate`, you'll get this:

```py
def upgrade():
  op.create_foreign_key(op.f('fk_characters_background_id_backgrounds'), 'characters', 'backgrounds', ['background_id'], ['id'])

def downgrade():
  op.drop_constraint(op.f('fk_characters_background_id_backgrounds'), 'characters', type_='foreignkey')
```

Thanks (unsurprisingly) to  Miguel Grinberg, creator of Flask Migrate, for having linked to the correct page in the Alembic docs that finally allowed me to solve this problem! [Someone had asked about this in an issue on Flask Migrate GitHub](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/445), and Miguel correctly pointed out that this was an Alembic issue, not a Flask Migrate issue.